# Is there any way to make the Google Play Store wishlist more useful?

Tags: google-play-store, search

The wishlist in the Google Play Store is barely useful.  It doesn't seem to be sortable or searchable.

Is there any way to make it more useful?

I've been using the MarketMarks app to get around the Play Store's limitations, but MarketMark's Backup and Restore function seems to be currently broken, which is a dealbreaker.